# Foundry --> readFile() ---> parseJson() error when field value uint with >18 digits

Tags: solidity, blockchain, testing, foundry

I am reading files with Foundry and using the jsonParse(path) method to retrieve the values.
When the numbers in the json file are greater that 1**18 I get the error `[FAIL. Reason: Failed to parse key $.poolTotalBalance]`. If I change the numeric value to 17 digits, it works perfectly.
Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I've found is to convert all numerical values within the json files to strings and then, in solidity, convert them to uint256, still would be good to have a solution avoiding this extra step.